# I created a Flask web app which users can access through OAuth 2.0: is this code secure enough?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, oauth-2.0

I'm worried about potential threats since this is my first web app, I'm not good at security and it is using a paid API so I don't want to lose money.
In my whole application, I'm storing all the secrets into secrets manager and retrieving them by information provided in environment variables.
However my biggest concern is the Flask code. Verified users should be able to access it through auth2.0 with gcp.

Am I following best practices or missing something in the following code?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('authentication.html')


@app.route("/login")
def login():
    authenticator = setup_authenticator()
    secret = authenticator.get_secret()

    google_client_id = secret['web']['client_id']

    client = WebApplicationClient(google_client_id)

    google_provider_config = requests.get(google_discovery_url).json()

    authorization_endpoint = google_provider_config["authorization_endpoint"]

    request_uri = client.prepare_request_uri(
        authorization_endpoint,
        redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
        scope=["openid", "email", "profile"],
    )

    return redirect(request_uri)


@app.route("/login/callback")
def callback():
    return redirect('/form')


@app.route('/form')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')


@app.route("/process_form", methods=['POST'])
async def process_form():
    do_stuff


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(ssl_context="adhoc", port=settings.port)
```

Comment: who do you consider to be a ```verified user```? Do you mean you're hosting with GCP? If so which of the GCP services are you using?

Comment: Yes I am using google cloud run, and with verified user I mean one of those users I added when I created the auth2 web client secret.